# Custom Member fields to be unique

Tags: freemember, member-management

I am using freemember forms to create my "registration" page. I have two custom member fields "employee last name" and "employee id". I added them in the "custom member fields" section. I need to make these two fields unique and fail the registration process if the values entered in the registration process are duplicates.

I could not find "unique" attribute in the custom member fields. Only "required" attribute. any help in this regards will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is anything in Freemember that you can use to force the values to be unique out of the box. Having said that you can do it with a bit of AJAX in your template. MadeByHippo posted an example of it on their blog a while back that might be of interest for you. [ClientSide Username Checking](http://www.madebyhippo.com/blog/view/clientside_username_checking_ee_and_jquery)

Comment: Since Carl's example uses segment variables, I recommend using the [Active Record](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/activerecord) plugin rather than the SQL module to minimize security risks from SQL injection.

Comment: That is a great point

Comment: I did the ajax call and tested with the member fields DB to force uniqueness.